# process stop and cannot continue

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

so i find there is a problem with my coding but i cant spot it

```
case 2:     
            char newAnswer1 = 'Y';
            if (pat1.getUreaLevel() > 0)
            {    

                System.out.print("The existing urea level is" + pat1.getUreaLevel());
                System.out.print("Do you want to overwrite the existing urea level?: ");
                newAnswer1 = sc.next().charAt(0);

            }

            if (newAnswer1 == 'y' || newAnswer1 == 'Y')
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the a value of urea level (mmol/l): ");


                double ureaLevel = sc.nextDouble();

                do
                {
                    double ureaLevel = sc.nextDouble();

                    if (ureaLevel < 0 || ureaLevel > 10)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The value entered is invalid.");
                        System.out.print("Please enter a new urea level (mmol/l) : ");

                    }

                }while(ureaLevel < 0 || ureaLevel > 10);
            }
```

my problem is when i try to enter a value of urea level after i enter the value(invalid or valid) it just stop and end the process. which part did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is here

```
double ureaLevel = sc.nextDouble(); //1

do
{
  double ureaLevel = sc.nextDouble(); //2
  /* ... */
}while(ureaLevel < 0 || ureaLevel > 10);
```

You are waiting for a `Double` twice on the first iteration (first time through the loop), it's probably just waiting for a second entry, not doing nothing like you say.

Solution? Just remove the first one:-

```
double ureaLevel;

do
{
  ureaLevel = sc.nextDouble(); //only one value fetched
  /* ... */
}while(ureaLevel < 0 || ureaLevel > 10);
```

Comment: I actually made a small mistake myself that I've just fixed.